# Making a signup form and login form using express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am basically making a simple website on my localhost that has a signup form and some other html elements. I managed to setup the signup process smoothly. So when the user fills in the form and submits it to the root route("/"), an email is sent to the subscriber containing a random password using nodemailer and then the password is to be used to login to the user dashboard. The whole data is submitted as a mongodb document which I had setup. Upto this the process goes smoothly and when the user does the signup, the mail is sent to the subscriber's email id and then they are redirected to the login page. So now I am confused about setting up the server.

```
    // index.js file
    
    const express = require("express");

    const app = express();
    const port = 5000;

    const mainApp = require("./main.js");
    const loginApp = require("./login.js");

    app
      .use(function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.hostname == "http://localhost:5000") {
          mainApp(req, res, next);
          console.log("main");
        } else if (req.hostname == "http://localhost:5000/login") {
          loginApp(req, res, next);
          console.log("login");
        }
      })
    .listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port: ${port}`));
```

I don't understand how can I import the whole `main.js` module(the root route where the signup form exists, and the form data is also posted to the root route) and the `login.js` module(the '/login' route where the login form exists.

How can I make `index.js` run both modules on the same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to achieve what you need:

1. Using `app.METHOD(PATH, HANDLER)`. Read more [ExpressJs routing basic](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html)

   // index.js file

   ```
   const express = require("express");

   const app = express();
   const port = 5000;

   const mainApp = require("./main.js");
   const loginApp = require("./login.js");

   // route for /

   app.get("/", function(req,res, next) {
     mainApp(req, res, next);
     console.log("main");
   });

   //  route for /login
   app.get("/", function(req,res, next) {
     loginApp(req, res, next);
     console.log("login");
   });

   app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port: ${port}`));
   ```

2. Using `express.Router`. This enables to break routing logic into modules. Use this option to handle routing in modules `Main.js` and `login.js`

   // main-router.js
   var express = require('express')
   var router = express.Router()
   const mainApp = require("./main.js");

   ```
   // handler for /
   router.get('/', function (req, res) {
     mainApp(req, res, next);
     console.log("main");
   });

   module.exports = router
   ```

import module in `index.js`

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

const mainRouter = require("./main-router.js");
const loginApp = require("./login.js");

// route for /

app.get("/", mainRouter);

//  route for /login
app.get("/", function(req,res, next) {
  loginApp(req, res, next);
  console.log("login");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port: ${port}`));
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't have any idea on how to export those modules. Both of your solutions look correct. It would be helpful if you tell me how can i export those modules(main.js and login.js) using `module.exports`. I know I am requiring those files using the variables mainApp and loginApp. But what is the correct way to write `module.exports` so that all `app.get` and `app.post` methods work without any hassle.

Comment: Does your current implementation work? with require() parts?

Comment: No, apparently I realized that what I was doing was etrmemly dumb and not good practice. So I had to fix the code and it works fine now on the same port. i just put every post and get request in the same file. But now my senior asked me to create a router folder and put all the routes over there. Thanks for your concern, its really appreciated.